# What is a good alternative to `ContractTranslator.encode_abi`

Tags: web3.py, abi, encoding

Since the `ethereum` Python library has been deprecated in May 2019, the `ContractTranslator.encode_abi` function is probably not the best way to turn Python argument lists into `calldata` strings. In particular, it doesn't support functions with the same name but different argument lists.

What is a better way to do this? I've been digging into `web3.py` `_utils` but they don't have a single reusable function for this. Any alternatives to use in Python?

I'm looking for a function with an equivalent signature to this:

```py
def encode_abi(abi, function_name: str, args: List[Any]) -> bytes:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web3 provides a `Contract.encodeABI` class method: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.encodeABI.

Answer (score 12):

#### With Brownie

[Brownie](https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie) allows you to generate calldata using the [`ContractTx.encode_input`](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-network.html#ContractTx.encode_input) method:

```py
>>> token
<Token Contract object '0x79447c97b6543F6eFBC91613C655977806CB18b0'>

>>> token.transfer.encode_input(accounts[0], 1000)
0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000000d36bdba474b5b442310a5bfb989903020249bba00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8
```

It handles [function overloading](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#function-overloading) with the [`OverloadedMethod`](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-network.html#overloadedmethod) class:

```py
>>> erc223.transfer
<OverloadedMethod object 'ERC223Token.transfer'>

>>> erc223.transfer['address,uint']
<ContractTx object 'transfer(address,uint256)'>

>>> erc223.transfer['address', 'uint256', 'uint256']
<ContractTx object 'transfer(address,uint256,uint256)'>
```

#### With `eth-abi`

If you prefer not to use a framework, [`eth-abi`](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-abi) provides several [encoding methods](https://eth-abi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/encoding.html):

```py
>>> import eth_abi

>>> eth_abi.encode_abi(['address', 'uint256'], (web3.eth.accounts[0], 1000)).hex()
0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000000d36bdba474b5b442310a5bfb989903020249bba00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8
```

Disclosure: I am the lead developer for Brownie.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, ultimately both approaches are not ideal because they imply already knowing what the function signature is. I'd want to go from a list of arguments in Python to infer which overloaded function needs to be used and then encoding on the back of that. This is what `web3.py` seems to be doing.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify this explicitly and state what the signature was for the old `ContractTranslator.encode_abi`.